# Implementation of Message Center of Urban Airship in android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com, urbancode

I am going to integrate Urban Airship with Android, but I am facing some issues,

What I implemented,

1. I added dependencies of urbanAirship,
2. I am able to get Notifications, using FCM key.

Issues,

1. I am not getting option of Message Center in UA admin panel
2. I am getting push notifications but not getting that message in MessageCenterFragment.

I am stuck from last 2 days,

Thanks,

Comment: can anyone help in integrating UrbanAirShip in android

Comment: I am able to get message in Inbox now, but not able to style @ralepinski can you please help

Comment: For styling take a look at https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android/#styling-android-mc Make sure the activity that youa re displaying the message center in contains that style.